# How to vectorize NumPy polyder function?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I would like to vectorize the NumPy function [`polyder`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyder.html), which computes derivatives of polynomials. Is there a simple way or a built-in function to do it?

With vectorize, I mean that if the input is an array of polynomials, the output would be the array with the derivative of the polynomials.

An example:

```
p = np.array([[3,4,5], [1,2]])
```

the output should be something like

```
np.array([[6, 4], [1]])
```

Comment: I added some ideas for when all the lists of coefficients have the same (possibly 0 padded) length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your subarrays, both input and output, can have different lengths, you are better off treating both as lists.

```
In [97]: [np.polyder(d) for d in [[3,4,5],[1,2]]]
Out[97]: [array([6, 4]), array([1])]
```

Your `p` is just a list in an expensive (timewise) `array` wrapper.

```
In [100]: p=np.array([[3,4,5],[1,2]])
In [101]: p
Out[101]: array([[3, 4, 5], [1, 2]], dtype=object)
```

There is little that you can do with such an array that you can't do just as well with a list.  Do some time tests.  You probably will find that iterating over the arrays of objects is slower than iteration over equivalent lists, especially if you take into account the time it takes convert a list to array.

It can also be tricky to create such arrays.  If all the sublists are the same length the result will be a 2d array.  Forcing them to be an object array takes special initiation.

A general rull of thumb is - if individual steps work with arrays or lists of different length, you probably can't vectorize.  That is, you can't form a rectangular 2d array and apply vector operations.

---

If the polynomial lists were all the same length, then `p` could be 2d, and the result could also be that:

```
In [107]: p=np.array([[3,4,5],[0,1,2]])

In [108]: p
Out[108]: 
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2]])

In [109]: np.array([np.polyder(i) for i in p])
Out[109]: 
array([[6, 4],
       [0, 1]])
```

In effect it is iterating over the rows of `p`, and then reassembling the result into an array.  There are some numpy functions that streamline iteration (but don't speed it up much), but I see little need for those here.

---

Looking at the code of this function, the core is:

```
p = NX.asarray(p)
n = len(p) - 1
y = p[:-1] * NX.arange(n, 0, -1)
```

which for this 2d array, (len 3) is:

```
In [117]: p[:,:-1]*np.arange(2,0,-1)
Out[117]: 
array([[6, 4],
       [0, 1]])
```

So if the number of polynomials are all the same, this simple multiplication gives the 1st order derivative coefficients.  And of course the rows can be padded so they are all the same.   So 'vectorization' is easier than I initially thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
p = np.array([[3,4,5], [1,2]])
np.array([np.polyder(coefficients) for coefficients in p]) # array([[6 4], [1]], dtype=object)
```

would fulfill your interface for your specific example. But [as hpaulj mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469035/674064), there's little sense in working with NumPy arrays instead of normal python lists here, and no actual (hardware-level) vectorization will happen. (Though, as with list comprehensions in general, the interpreter would be free to employ other means of parallelism to compute them.)